# Auto-renewable subscription and the receipt in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription

My app has auto-renewable subscription. Now I am testing the subscription in sandbox mode. I verify a receipt locally on a device.

It looks like the receipt does not update automatically, because the receipt always has the same `subscriptionExpirationDate` and it does not change.

For example my test auto renewable subscription has 1 week duration. As I understand it should refresh 5 times/per sandbox account every 3 min and after it should be in `expired` state. In my case when I initially subscribe as a new sandbox user:

```
validateTime() serverTime:2018-07-22 10:24:16, receiptDate:2018-07-22 10:26:16
```

But when `serverTime` will be `2018-07-22 10:27:00` => nothing happens. The `subscriptionExpirationDate` is the same: `2018-07-22 10:26:16`

How to obtain a new version of the receipt locally? And how to do it in the best way?

Comment: If your app is in the foreground when the subscription renews then a new transaction will be presented to your payment queue observer.  One of the first things your app should do when it launches is instantiate a payment queue observer.  The second thing it should do is refresh the receipt and check for updated subscriptions.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have added  `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)` in
 `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` and `SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)` in `applicationWillTerminate`. But how to refresh the receipt?

Comment: @Paulw11 - call SKProductsRequest.start() as early as possible?

Comment: You can get the receipt from your bundle https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2

Comment: @Paulw11 - yes, I verify the receipt locally according to the document you mentioned. It is auto-renewable subscription - `Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL` has the latest version of the receipt automatically, hasn't it? Do I need some extra logic to refresh it?

Comment: On launch I believe that the receipt is refreshed automatically.  You can use [SKReceiptRefreshRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skreceiptrefreshrequest) to manually refresh the receipt

Comment: @Paulw11 - This is the problem - it does not in my app... Ok, I am going to try `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` to refresh it manually.

Comment: I did write a library for [receipt monitoring](https://github.com/paulw11/subscription-monitor) although I haven't looked at it for a while so it might need some Swift 4 tweaks, but you could look at it for some ideas.

Comment: @Paulw11 - Thank you for you advice. Now I am trying to use you library. In some reason the receipt didn't refresh even with SKReceiptRefreshRequest.